# How do you say that you want to "recover" the hours you were not at work?

Tags: expressions

I want to take two days off from work, but I want to work over the weekend to compensate for the missing days. So I have to send an email to my client and I don't know what the correct expression for this is.

Comment: I would probably say 'I'll make up the time at the weekend'. Or, if you want to be more formal, simply tell them the dates when you will be available for work so they can see a schedule of days/hours.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. A colleague said I could say "I will catch up on missing hours during the weekend". Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that's fine. I think it would depend on how well you know the client and how informal you can be, and whether you think they might be concerned about delays. You don't want to sound too casual if you're dealing with a company rather than one-to-one.

Comment: Ok, I see now. Could you add your comments as an answer in order to accept it? :)

Comment: Your colleague might have better insight as to how such a request would be best worded in your particular situation.  "Catching up on missing hours" would put the focus more on your pay for that week, assuming that it's an hourly wage type job.   At a salaried job, "making up the time"  would probably make more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would depend on how formal the situation is.

If dealing with a company or a new client you don't want to sound too casual as they might be concerned about delays and you may come across as unprofessional. I would give them a list of dates when you are available for work so they can see that you will be working at the weekend. Or you could say "Unfortunately I will not be available on [days] but I will be able to give this my full attention at the weekend."

In a more informal situation, with a client who knows and trusts you, there are a number of expressions you could use:

> I'll make up the extra time/missing hours at the weekend.
>  I'll
>   catch up at the weekend.
>  I'm free to work on this later in the
>   week.